# How to Show an Image in OS X with C code in XCode

Tags: c, xcode, image

I am writing a C application, and I am developing in XCode.  I would like my code to create a window and display an image in that window.  If possible, I would like the image to be resized if a user changes the size of the displayed window, but this is not at all necessary.

I am specifically avoiding C++ and ObjectiveC.  I need to work with straight C.  Is this possible?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're making a command-line app, you have to use keyboard (ascii) characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to learn Objective-C. It's not difficult to pick up, especially if you already have a strong understanding of C. (It's a much smaller and simpler extension of C than C++, for instance.)

Your options other than that are quite limited:

- There's Carbon, Apple's legacy C framework for UI development. **Using it is not recommended**. Carbon was never updated to support 64-bit applications, and lacks many features that have been added to Cocoa since the 64-bit transition (~2005). It's also very awkward to write an application in, as it was designed in large part to ease porting of applications written for Classic Mac OS.
- There's also X11, with an appropriate UI library like GTK. **I wouldn't recommend this either**. Neither X11 nor any UI libraries for it are installed by default -- they must be installed by the user -- and applications which use X11 have a significantly different interface from native applications.
- A third-party UI library. Most of the ones I can think of offhand (QT, wxWidgets, and FLTK) require C++, though. [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/download/macos.php) does have a C interface and natively supports a macOS interface, but it's not particularly native.
- A library specific to your use case. Impossible to recommend one without knowing more about what you're trying to do.
- Nothing. That's right, nothing at all. If you just need to let the user view an image, you can save it to a file and use the `open` command-line tool to open it in the Preview application. It's janky, but it's also really easy.